# Does the order of inf and not-inf matter in pandas.groupby.agg(sum) function?

Tags: python, group-by, inf

I tried to calculate the sum of a grouped `pd.DataFrame` (or `pd.Series`) containing `inf`. Thereby, I figured out that the location of the `inf` in the original pd.DataFrame will influence the result beeing `nan` or `inf`.

Here is an example:
Let us assume, there is a Series `df` with a two-level MultiIndex:

```
mid = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuple([('a',1), ('a',2), ('b',1), ('b',2), ('c',1), ('c',2)])
df = pd.Series(np.array([np.inf, 1, 1, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf]), index=mid)

df
a  1    inf
   2    1.0
b  1    1.0
   2    inf
c  1    inf
   2    inf
dtype: float64
```

If I calculate the sum of the aggregated Series, I get `nan` for groups `a` and `c`, but `inf` for group `b`:

```
df.groupby(level=[0]).agg(sum)

a    NaN
b    inf
c    NaN
dtype: float64
```

I would expect `inf` for all of them, as `(np.inf+1)==(1+np.inf)` and `(np.inf+1)==(np.inf+np.inf)` both result in `True`.

The result is the same for `np.nansum`.

There have been known bugs with inf and pd.agg(sum):

- [BUG: Groupby summing over infinity values yields NaN #54161](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54161)
- [BUG: inconsistent treatment of numpy.Inf between groupby.sum() and groupby.apply(lambda: _grp: _grp.sum()) #53606](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53606)
- [BUG: inconsistent result when groupby then sum values that contain inf #43292](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43292)

Nevertheless, they are all either closed or completed and do not address the order of inf in the `pd.Series`.

Can somebody explain me, why the order of `inf` matters in this calculation and why the sum of two `inf` results in `nan`?

My `pandas` version is `1.4.4`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour on `pandas==2.1.0`. I get `inf` in every case. Maybe update the pandas module?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade my pandas in this environment due to the dependencies of other packages (ESRI arcpy).